# how can i set time and date for notification

Tags: android, notifications

in the notification manager we use this method to set time and date to fire notification

```
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

but the `System.currentTimeMillis()` get back the current time on device but i want to add specified time like ( Friday 15:00 )

how can i do that ?? how can i set this time in milliseconds and load it up in `.setWhen`

thanks in advance

this code i use

```
Notification.Builder builder =
new Notification.Builder(MyActivity.this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setTicker(“Notification”)
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
.setSound(
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(
RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
.setLights(Color.RED, 0, 1);
Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
```

Comment: setWhen(long time) IS NOT used to set date and time to fire notification. Please see documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setWhen(long)

Comment: import java.util.*;
...
builder.setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() );

Answer (score 9):

You should use the Java [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to specify a date. Instantiate a `Calendar` object using the `getInstance()` factory method. By default, the instance will be initialized with the current date and time for the default time zone of your machine. `Calendar` contains different `set()` methods to specify a date, choose one that's more appropriate for your needs and use it to specify the date you need. Then call the `getTimeInMillis()` method, which will return specified date in milliseconds. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
...
builder.setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() );
```

Comment: What happens if you are using custom design for notification? Is there some way to use ".setWhen()" indicating which view should show the "time" value?

Answer (score 1):

As @Deimos already mentioned in the comments, the 'setWhen' function only sets the timestamp for the certain notification for displaying in the notification, it is NOT the timestamp to 'FIRE' or trigger the notification at a specific point of time. It is part of the Notification(.Builder) class that seems only to have support for creating a custom notification.
FIRING a notification e.g. notification triggered at sunday 1pm to remind the user of sth at the weekend can be realized e.g. locally with the help of AlarmManager and Broadcast and the Alarm Manager is firing the notification according to given date and time or remotely with any server instances like FCM for Android.
I hope this cleared any possiblly upcoming misunderstandings.