# How to show notifications by turn?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Let I have a set of times. For example,`{"11:40","11:55","16:15","20:05"}`. 
Firstly, I need to show some notification at `11:40` , then at `11:55`  and so on,until the end. Each notification has its own title and text. And they shouldn't be updated(I mean that if notification that was showed at 11:40 was not pressed or removed from status bar by user,next notification shouldn't be put over the previous notification). I know how to show notification using `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` , but I don't have a right idea how to solve this problem. I imagine the solution as follows: When app opened for the first time , I set alarm to show notification at `index = 0` ( where `index` is index of array of times). When first notification was shown , I update `index` and set alarm for the next notification and so on , until the end. At the end , all operation cancels and no notification will be shown.But I don't imagine how to construct that idea. How to solve this problem? Is it possible? Do I need a `Service` for this? Can you give helpful steps to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call this method at given times.

```
    private void notificationManager(Context context, String message,long time) {

    try {
        long when = //Set your own time here by passing it in the function

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Log.v("message", "," + message);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);


        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setTicker(message);
        builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
        builder.setWhen(when);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);


        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledOnMS = 100;
        notification.ledOffMS = 100;
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Just pass time in the builder.setWhen in milliseconds which you can do by creating a Calendar object and setting the time in it. It will automatically schedule those notifications and show them on their respective time. Use a for loop to pass all the time and call the function.

Hope this hepls

Comment: setWhen(long time) IS NOT used to set date and time to fire notification. Please see documentation:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setWhen(long)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458705/how-can-i-set-time-and-date-for-notification